# Creating A Loop to name files in BASH

Tags: bash

I need to create a script that creates the number of files a user specifies, using the name and file ext the user specifies. My loop fails, and only one file is created.

```
#!/bin/bash

#arguements variables

file=$1
ext=$2
numFiles=$3
count=0

#for loop for 5 repetitions

while [ $3 -ge count ]; do
touch ${1}.${2}.${3}

done

echo " "$3" Files where created using the name "$1" and extension "$2" "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to specify extension, you could use [shell parameter extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). You could also use `for` [loop with index](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
FILE_NAME=$1
NUM_OF_FILES=$2 || 0
for ((IDX=0; IDX < NUM_OF_FILES; IDX+=1)) ; do
    # for fname.tar.gz result is fname0.tar.gz, fname1.tar.gz, ...
    touch "${FILE_NAME%%.*}$IDX.${FILE_NAME#*.}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To create `count` files with name `file` and extension `ext` and suffixed with a number from 1 to `count`, try:

```
for i in $(seq "$count"); do touch "$file.$ext.$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increase count. Try this:

```
#arguements variables

file=$1
ext=$2
numFiles=$3
count=0

#for loop for 5 repetitions

while [ ${numFiles} -ge ${count} ]; do
    touch ${1}.${2}.${count}
    let "count+=1"
done

echo " "$3" Files where created using the name "$1" and extension "$2" "
```